# Javascript class property returning undefined despite assignment

Tags: javascript, class, promise, constructor, properties

I cant seem to re-define the `authToken` property at all, and outside the scope of the constructor, it just returns undefined no matter what, whether i'm referencing it in File 1 or File 2. Below is some example code.

File 1:

```
class Clazz {
    authToken;

    constructor() {
        getAuthToken().then((token) => {
            this.authToken = token;
        });
    }
}

const getAuthToken = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        adalcontext.acquireTokenWithClientCredentials(resourceapi, clientId, clientSecret, (error, tokenResponse) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(new Error(`Failed to authenticate: ${error.message}`));
            } else {
                resolve(tokenResponse.accessToken);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

File 2:

```
const clazz = new Clazz();

console.log(clazz.authToken) // => returns undefined
```

I have tried many different things but none seem to be working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Your constructor calls an asynchronous function. The token property will not be set until that operation completes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to access `authToken` before it's assigned in an async operation. Make `authToken` a promise and wait it fullfilled:

```
class Clazz {
    authToken;

    constructor() {
        this.authToken = getAuthToken();
    }
}

...

// in a module or async function:

const clazz = new Clazz();

console.log(await clazz.authToken)
```

Another option would be an async factory:

```
class Clazz {

    static async create(){
        return new Clazz(await getAuthToken());
    }   

    authToken;

    constructor(authToken) {
        if(!authToken){
            throw new Error('Cannot create Clazz without authToken');
        }
        this.authToken = authToken;
    }
}

...

// in a module or async function:

const clazz = await Clazz.create();

console.log(clazz.authToken)
```